# How to keep same version for all the projects while generating NuGet package using pack command

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've following structure for a .NET Framework project:
`-->ProjectSoln -------->ClassLibProj1 -------->ClassLibProj2 -------->ConsumerLibProj3`
I've defined GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs file at solution level and added the reference to this file in all
the 3 projects. ConsumerLibraryProj3 has project reference to ClassLibraryProj1 and ClassLibraryProj2.
I've added nuspec file in the ConsumerLibProj3 that contains $version$.
I'm generating Nuget Package for the ConsumerLibraryProj3 using following command
`nuget pack ConsumerLibProj3.csproj -includereferencedprojects -verbosity detailed`
The package gets generated successfully, but the version of the ClassLibProj1 and ClassLibProj2 dlls
in the package is not the latest. e.g. in the package ConsumerLibProj3.dll has version 1.0.0.2
whereas the ClassLibProj1.dll and ClassLibProj2.dll has version 1.0.0.1. The expectation is that all
the three dll's should have same version because the the version is coming from the
GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs file. The solution is using .NET Framework type project. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At last I was able to resolve this issue by forcing the nuget to use release configuration while packing. Surprisingly, I was building the solution with Release profile but still nuget was getting confused somehow. I used following command

```
nuget pack ConsumerLibProj3.csproj -includereferencedprojects -build -properties configuration=release -verbosity detailed
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/?_ga=2.126979533.1703891993.1616377674-584939326.1612145624):)

Comment: Since you have a workaround about your issue, please do not forget to [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/?_ga=2.254203080.1550376119.1617587971-584939326.1612145624):)